# classes or objects within a class/object

Tags: python, tkinter

I read related posts but they didn't satisfy me.

Using tkinter i coded a class Musicsheet. Then I wrote classes of notes like wholeNote & halfNote, etc. After instantiaing MusicSheet followed by an instance of WholeNote, it looked ok, with the whole note on the music sheet. However, when I instantiated a half note the whole note had disappeared with just the half note on the sheet;it looks like halfNote had also instantiated ( sub classed?) a new music sheet thus previous notes/objects aren't there. This result in that the latest instance is always the only one on the sheet.

Thanks for the replies. Here are additional info:

```
 class Musicsheet(Frame):
    .......TCanvas initialization..
 class WholeNote(MusicSheet):
   ......
 class HalfNote(MusicSheet):
   def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2)
   self.can.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2)
   .....
  more notes classes follow
```

Comment: Can you illustrate with a shortened version of your code? What you're trying to describe sounds really wrong for some reason.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, and you haven't shown us any code. We can't diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: You DO have a base class (`Note`, perhaps?) for `WholeNote`, `HalfNote`, etc?

Comment: The code you added is useless to us. You need to show us _actual_, _runnable_ code. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code:

Your note classes are derived from MusicSheet. I suppose you want the notes to be part of the sheet, not an instance of the Sheet. If you derive them from MusicSheet, the **init** of a Note would create a new instance of MusicSheet, not be added to the MusicSheet.

For Notes i recommend using `Tkinter.CanvasItem` class for inheritance.
(Type should be polygon for everything that is not a half/full rest or full note)

Using `self.can.create_oval` should be done in MusicSheet, not in Note Classes, as `self.can` should refer to the MusicSheet.